# Define function and classes separately from their declarations

Tags: python

I was wondering, for human readability purposes, if it is possible to separate the declarations for functions and classes from their definitions in Python? For example, in C you can do the following for functions:

```c
// Declaration:
void my_func(int some_param);
...
int main(){

}
...
void my_func(int some_param){
   // Function definition here.
}
```

OR

```c
extern void my_func(int some_param);
```

Where it is defined somewhere else. Likewise, in terms of OOP, C++ you can do the following:

```cpp
class SomeClass {
    SomeClass();
    SomeClass(int some_param);

    void some_method(int const& some_param);
    void another_method(int another_param);
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    
}

SomeClass::SomeClass(){
    // Definition of empty constructor
}

SomeClass::SomeClass(int some_param){
    // Definition of constructor with some_param
}

void SomeClass::some_method(int const& some_param){
    // Same idea
}

void SomeClass::another_method(int another_param){
    // Ditto ^
}
```

Now I know that Python is incredibly different than C/C++, but I would like to separate my function and class declarations from their definitions in Python as well. Is this possible? Something like:

```py
# Declare function:
def some_func(some_param: int)
...
# Define it somewhere else:
def some_func(some_param: int):
    # definition
```

and

```py
# Declare it:
class SomeClass:
    someField: int

    some_method(some_param: int)
    another_method(another_param: int)

# Define it (somehow?):
# I am not sure how to even attempt to do this part
```

Comment: In python there is no declaration. @Bob

Comment: Generally this separation isn't used in Python. The closest equivalent would be mypy stubs https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html

Comment: There's no declarations in Python. `class` statements are executable — so the answer is "no".

Comment: Also, python's not a typed language, so it makes no sense to have type declarations.

Comment: @Pythony I understand that it isn't a typed language, but the point is to define the function beforehand so that another developer can have a "quick look" so to speak without having to scroll through the bodies of the functions themselves. Same idea for classes: they could look at what methods and subsequent parameters a given class allows without scrolling through the whole class's definitions. But based off of the comments, it seems as though Python lacks this ability unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the best answer I can find is from @togglejoy, which involves using stub files. You can include `.pyi` files in your projects, which are called stub files. In the case of my example, I could "declare" (so to speak) my class in a `myClass.pyi` file:

```py
class SomeClass:
    someField: int

    def some_method(some_param: int): ...
    def another_method(another_param: int): ...
```

and then define it in `myClass.py` file:

```py
class SomeClass:
    someField: int = 0

    def some_method(some_param: int):
        # Definition

    def another_method(another_param: int):
        # Definition
```

Same idea for functions. And you can even overload them with the `typing` module. In `myFunc.pyi`:

```py
from typing import overload

@overload
def some_func(some_param: int): ...

@overload 
def some_func(some_param: str): ...
```

and in `myFunc.py`:

```py
def some_func(some_param):
    # Handle both scenarios here
```

Although this is better than nothing, as far as I understand it, the `.pyi` files don't actually get enforced in the real "definitions" because, well, they aren't real "declarations": it would be nice if the had a way to enforce it.

Comment: ABC https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html can be used to provide enforceable interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by all the no answers.

In C "A header file is a file with extension .h which contains C function declarations and macro definitions to be shared between several source files. "

In python we have libraries i.e. standard libraries. Example import math (a library) in IDLE type math. and IDLE will show a list of defined functions.

We make our own libraries and import them.

Type ourlib. and editors and IDEs will show the parameters. or even type >>> help(ourlib.function) and help will display information on the function.

Create library mylib.py has the definition.

```
def add_two(x,y):
    """
    Add x and y and return the sum
    """
    return sum([x,y])
```

use_mylib.py use the definition

```
import mylib
print(mylib.add_two(5,8)) # vscode showed parameters required and even int type hint.
```

output

```
13
```

Comment: I propose the answer above as meeting the objective of, "to define the function beforehand so that another developer can have a "quick look" so to speak without having to scroll through the bodies"

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but your examples are of the utilization of a particular class/function in a file other than the one it resides in (i.e. import the module and then invoke it in the other python file). This is not what I was asking (or at least attempting to ask): I want to declare the function/class separately from its definition. I am not asking how to modulize the code into separate files. What I mean by "quick look" is that they can see the declaration without seeing the body thereof: your example is simply invoking the method, not defining it.