# Pylance does not see stub files

Tags: python, python-typing, stub, pylance

I have the following structure:

```
mypackage/
├─ subpackage/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ module.py
│  ├─ module.pyi
├─ __init__.py
```

File `mudule.pyi` contains:

```
class Apple:
    tree: Tree

class Tree:
    apples: Apple
```

No errors so far. File `module.py` contains:

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, tree: Tree):
        pass

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, apples: Apple):
        pass
```

And here the following error is reported by `Pylance`, saying the name 'Tree' is undefined (also by pyflakes)
[image: Name 'Tree' undefined]
Is there a way to tell `Pylance` there is stub file or maybe I must put stub file in another place?
[image: Problem2]

Comment: The problem is that the `Apple` class definition is first in the module, before the `Tree` class has been defined.

Comment: @JohnGordon, just to solve this problem I use stub files — to tell checkers there will be implementation of the `Tree` class, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382261/define-function-and-classes-separately-from-their-declarations)